# Take the difference between two polygons using Shapely?

Tags: python-3.x, polygon, geopandas, shapely

This code finds the intersection of two polygons and create a polygon out of the intersection. My aim is to do the exact `opposite`.  I would like to create a polygone which has a hole in it in others words it excludes the intersection from the big polygone.

The code i managed to construct is:

```
from shapely.geometry import shape,Polygon,MultiPolygon,mapping
import geopandas as gpd

g1 = geomap
print(geomap)
g2 = geomap_world
print(geomap_world)

data=[]
for index, orig in g1.iterrows():
    for index2, ref in g2.iterrows():
        if ref['geometry'].intersects(orig['geometry']):                
            data.append({'geometry':ref['geometry'].intersection(orig['geometry'])}) 

df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data,columns=['geometry'])
```

where df is :

```
162  POLYGON ((-2.16991 35.16840, -1.79299 34.52792...
```

But I am looking to construct the opposite result which is a polygone that excludes the intersection. Any hint?

I also tried `symmetric_difference` instead of `intersection` as follows:

```
data=[]
for index, orig in g1.iterrows():
    for index2, ref in g2.iterrows():
        if ref['geometry'].symmetric_difference(orig['geometry']):
               data.append({'geometry':ref['geometry'].symmetric_difference(orig['geometry'])})     

df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data,columns=['geometry'])
```

The result is a polygon that is equal to the intersection i would like to exclude. Where I am going wrong?

Comment: if you try not in a loop but just 2 polygons does `symmetric_difference` work as you expect? I wonder if that is what you want you just need to edit the condition `if .intersects`

Comment: Do not use `intersect` but use `bigpoly_object.difference(hole_object)`.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen  i already tried `df1=gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': geomap.geometry, 'df1':[1]})
df2=gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': geomap_world.geometry, 'df2':[1]})`   `res_union = df1.overlay(df2, how='symmetric_difference')` but i get an error  `ImportError: Spatial indexes require either `rtree` or `pygeos` `   i tried `import pygeos` but no success

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen  also tried  `s= gpd.GeoSeries(geomap.geometry)
s2=gpd.GeoSeries(geomap_world.geometry)
s.symmetric_difference(s2)`  but i get this `0      None
162    None
dtype: geometry`  no what i expected

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen  i also tried your suggestion which is replace `intersects` with `symmetric_difference` but the result were not what I expected.                                     
        `if ref['geometry'].symmetric_difference(orig['geometry']):
         
            data.append({'geometry':ref['geometry'].symmetric_difference(orig['geometry'])}) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The geospatial predicate you need to use in the creation of a polygon with a hole is called `difference`. Try this code. It plots a country with a hole in it.

```
import geopandas as gpd
#from shapely.geometry import Polygon    
# Use naturalearth_lowres' `world` data for demonstration
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
# Get the polygon geometry of a country
poly = world.geometry.values[12]
# Create a `buffer` polygon from rep-point of the selected
#   country, and call it `hole`
hole = world.geometry.values[12].representative_point().buffer(0.5)
# Do the `difference` spatial operation, 
#   on Jupyter notebook you will get the result as graphic
poly.difference(hole)
```

[image: image1]

Comment: Thank you. Why `[12]`?  why `buffer`?  also how can i replace `hole` with my polygon? in other words, how can i adapt your code to my situation? is it possible to amend your answer? Thank you

Comment: @bravopapa Better amend your question with some data and important steps.

Comment: I have amended my question. How is it possible to adapt your code to my case? I need to remove small polygone from the world/country polygon. Unless Iam wrong our code i believe suggests something else because `hole` is taken from `world`.

Answer (score 0):

This answer worked for me. it gave me a polygone with a hole in it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re    
# Geospatial libraries
import geopandas as gpd    
import glob    
from shapely.geometry import shape,Polygon,MultiPolygon,mapping, LineString, Point    

#geomap contains the polygon that i would like to extract (ref)
geomap = import_shapes_list(path_to_data,shapes_folder,crs='EPSG:4326')

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
# world contains the big polygon (orig)
geomap_world=world[world['name']=='Morocco']


g1=gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': geomap.geometry, 'df1':[1]})
g2=gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': geomap_world.geometry, 'df2':[1]})
# double iteration through the coordinates and takes the `difference` between polygones
data=[]
for index, orig in g1.iterrows():
    for index2, ref in g2.iterrows():
        if ref['geometry'].difference(orig['geometry']):       
            data.append({'geometry':ref['geometry'].difference(orig['geometry'])})    


df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data,columns=['geometry'])
```

Thank you for all your comments and guidance

For more information, you can look at the documentation below:

https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#set-theoretic-methods

https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.difference.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).